# How Groovy can save console output to file?

Tags: groovy, soapui

i have a project in Soapui and a groovy code which run all tests of the project.
The result can be seen in the output console.
So what i want is to to save the content of the output ina file.

in Java we can do this:

```
//create a buffered reader that connects to the console, we use it so we can read lines
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

      //read a line from the console
      String lineFromInput = in.readLine();

      //create an print writer for writing to a file
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("c:/temp7/output.txt"));

      //output to the file a line
      out.println(lineFromInput);

      //close the file 
      out.close();
```

Is there an equivalent code in groovy ?
THank you

Comment: I believe that you would run the project from soapui tool. Right? But where do you run the above java code in case to collect the output? By the way, the same code should working groovy too as it is.

Comment: I run this code from a groovy step at the end of all test . I tried the same code but i got errors, it should be something like this def file = new File('c:/temp7/sample.txt')

file.withWriter('UTF-8') {
    it.writeLine 'Adding this text to the file.'
} Here i should add the content of the console output.

Comment: You mean to say, the project is run using from a groovy step itself?

Comment: yes, the groovy is added as a step and running from soapui

Comment: May be you can have first three statements in the top, then run the project, and finally have last two statements in the groovy step you have, then see if it helps.

Comment: By the way you should do the imports to those classes you are using in the groovy step, like you do in java.

Comment: Have you seen the soapui.log file? Have you seen the command line testrunner, which will save all the results, including the console, for you? http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-functional-tests.html

Comment: yes i have seen the testrunner in Soapui but i want to hard code by myself,

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can read the console output.
But you ned to execute your tests from the GUI and not from command line with testrunner.

```
// Can be altered to 'soapUI log', 'http log', 'jetty log', 'error log' etc.
def logArea = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.logMonitor.getLogArea( "http log" );

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context) 
if( logArea !=null )
{
   def model = logArea.model
   // only continue of logArea not empty
   if( model.size > 0 )            
   for( c in 0..(model.size-1) )

   // DO SOMETHING HERE... could write to file, could run assertions, etc.
   writeToFile(model.getElementAt(c))               
}
```